# Button to replace blank block with div table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xslt

I have inserted many table formats into a div opening and closing tag, however I am trying to make it work in an XSL file. I don't want a button which toggles the div but replaces it. For example, it will start out like an blank space then once you click, the div - table will appear. Disregard the xsl:value-of tags.

Can anyone help me out? This is my code:

```
<div id="table1"><h3><b>Sydney @ 01/10/2017 15:30:45</b></h3>

<table width="40%" border="0">

<tr>
<td align="center" width="20%">
<xsl:value-of select="dayOfWeek" />
<i style="color:blue">FRI</i>  10/13
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="overall" />
<i>Partly sunny</i>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" width="20%">
<xsl:value-of select="overallCode[@partlySunny]" />
<img src="http://www.uow.edu.au/~dong/w3/assignment/a7/partlySunny.png" />
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="highest" />
<xsl:value-of select="lowest" />
<b style="font-size:200%;">21&#176;</b>/10&#176;
</td>
</tr>

</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var tablex = document.getElementById("table1");
if (tablex.style.display === "none") {
    tablex.style.display = "block";
} else {
    tablex.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle table by adding:

```
<button onclick="toggleTable();"></button>

function toggleTable() {
    var tablex = document.getElementById("table1");
    tablex.style.display = (tablex.style.display == "table") ? "none" : "table";
}
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: This only toggles the table... I want to not toggle it, but display it once. @JonathanWang

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood, so what you want is to press the button, and then shows the table inside the <div>?

Comment: Yes that is all, except I want it to show in a XSL document. Does this change anything?